# Visual Studio publish generates .pdb file despite using DebugType=None

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, publish-profiles

I'm publishing a console app from within Visual Studio using the following publish profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>x64</Platform>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp5.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\netcoreapp5.0\publish\</PublishDir>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>False</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>True</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>True</PublishReadyToRun>
    <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>True</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>

    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

My goal is to not emit any .pdb files (debug symbols) in the publish output folder.
This doesn't completely work as intended.

The .pdb file of the console app project is not generated - as expected, but the debug symbols for the business logic project it references is for some reason generated. Is this a bug?

I can hack this by adding a conditional statement to the project file of the business logic library, but that it something I'd like to avoid as I think all the relevant information for publishing the app should reside in the publish profile.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
   <DebugType>none</DebugType>
   <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`<DebugType>none</DebugType><DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>` will only prevent the generation of the  current project's **pdb** file. And if your main project referenced a second project, these nodes will not prevent the the second project's **pdb** file in the main project. **This is designed by that.**

**And** if you want to prevent the referenced project's **pdb** file being generated into the publish folder of the main project, you should use this node additionally:

```
<AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>*.pdb</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
```

**Solution**

Add these in your `pubxml` file:

```
<DebugType>none</DebugType>
<DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
<AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>*.pdb</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
```

Comment: This is interesting. I can't seem to find any documentation on this setting. Judging by its name, shouldn't its logic be inverted?

Comment: The node is quite a bit special. `*.pdb` or `-.pdb` means that exclude such suffix file on the main project while `.pdb` means that include such files. A bit flexible! And there is no such obvious official document to explain that. You can test with my method and give us any feedback about that.

Comment: So in your side, you want to exclude the referenced project's pdb file, you should use `*.pdb`

Comment: Great answer, really helped me. It works for visual studio 2019+winform+.net5 as well.

Comment: I ended up doing this but also added the nuclear option of `<ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>bin\**\*.pdb</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>` because this worked for all referenced projects except the one that was being published.