# How to avoid copying referenced project config to bin folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

Good morning, dear community.

I want to ask about copying of config file of referenced project. I have been trying to resolve my issue for almost two days, but didn't achive any result.

The problem is that I have MyFinance.Repositories class library which contains its MyFinance.Repositories.appsetting.json file. The value of "Copy to output directoy" property for it is "Copy always".

[image]

Also, I have MyFinance.Api project, which has reference to MyFinance.Repositories.
[image: MyFinance.Api]

When I build MyFinance.Api, the MyFinance.Repositories.appsetting.json is copied to MyFinance.Api\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1 folder. [image]

And the deal is that I want to prevent it. The best assumption, that I had found is to use ResolveAssemblyReference task with AllowedRelatedFileExtensions property.

The snippet of MyFinance.Api.scproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyFinance.Repositories\MyFinance.Repositories.csproj">
      <Targets>
        <ResolveAssemblyReference AllowedRelatedFileExtensions=".xml;.pdb"></ResolveAssemblyReference>
      </Targets>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

But it doesn't work. So, please help me with that)
Thank you in advance.

P.S. The property "Copy to output directoy" of MyFinance.Repositories.appsetting.json must be "Copy always".
P.P.S. Deleting this file in post-build is also invalid.

Comment: class libraries don't need a config file, you put the settings in the config file of the executable that is using the library. So don't bother with all the complication you are creating.

Comment: @Crowcoder, thank you for reply. The deal is that the situation I have described occurs with production code. The MyFinanceApi project is just for example, which illustrate my production situation. I can't delete that class library config.

Comment: You can write post build target that will remove your file, but it's a bad solution

Comment: @T.Gryts, any update about this issue?

Comment: @T.Gryts, any update about this issue? Does Perry's answer helps you handle the issue, if it helps, please do not forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Comment: @T.Gryts, any update about this issue? Does Perry's answer helps you handle the issue, if it helps, please do not forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `MyFinance.Repositories.appsetting.json` is a content resource json file rather than a runtime output file. So the `AllowedRelatedFileExtensions` and `AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions` properties have no job to handle the resource files.

The properties node can only [handle the generated runtime, output files(pdb,dev.json,xml,...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64839368/visual-studio-publish-generates-pdb-file-despite-using-debugtype-none/64852107#64852107) rather than the copy if newer resource files.

You can test it with a txt resource files with `<AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>*.txt</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>` and the output `pdb` file with `<AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>*.pdb</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>`, and then you will find the difference.

**Solution**

**So** the best solution is to delete the file, add these under `MyFinance.Api.csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="DeleteFile" AfterTargets="_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory">
    <Delete Files="$(TargetDir)MyFinance.Repositories.appsettings.json"></Delete>
</Target>
```