# How to stop copying referenced project's AppSettings.json and web.config to output folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild, .net-5

I have ASP.NET Core 5 project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

that contains appsettings.json.  Build action is not customized: Content, Copy if Newer.

How do I reference this project in another csproj so that the appsettings.json won't be included in output folder?

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\app\App.csproj">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>compile</IncludeAssets>
  <ExcludeAssets>contentfiles; build; analyzers; buildtransitive</ExcludeAssets>
</ProjectReference>
```

Answer (score 0):

In normal, the `AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions` property can [handle the runtine, output files from the referenced project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64839368/visual-studio-publish-generates-pdb-file-despite-using-debugtype-none/64852107#64852107) like the second project's pdb,xml,dev.json,... rather than the copy if newer resource files. And there is no such direct msbuild property on the first project to prevent the referenced resource files being copied into it.

**As a test**, you could try the `AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions` property on the main poject rather than the refenced project with this:

```
<AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>*.pdb</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
```

You will find that the pdb file of **App** project is lost. That is true.

While you tested it with `a new copy if newer txt resource file` from App project, that  never works.

```
<AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>*.txt</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
```

**Solution**

So far, the best function is to delete the file after the main `_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory` system target which is charge of coping all the resource, output files from the referenced project into the main project:

```
<Target Name="DeleteFile" AfterTargets="_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory">
        <Delete Files="$(TargetDir)xxx.appsettings.json"></Delete> 
</Target>
```

Comment: The problem is, that both, referenced and referencing project have appsetttings.json files,  so I can't delete it just like that

Comment: @Liero, Project A references Project B and you want to prevent the Project B's appsettings.json file into Project A's output folder. What I meant is that you should put the xml code into Project A.csproj file. And it will delete the `Project B.appsettings.json` file automatically. And you should write the full name of the `Project B.appsettings.json` file. For an example, if the json file is named as `Project B.appsettings.json` of project B, you should write `<Delete Files="$(TargetDir)\Project B.appsettings.json"></Delete>`.

Comment: Also, If you use the default file named like `appsettings.json` files, the default files, the full name are both the same in `Project A` and `Project B`. When `Project A` references `Project B`, the output folder of `Project A` only contains one single file `appsettings.json` from `Project A` because it is the main project and `appsettings.json` file from the Project B is overwritten by the file of main project A. So you does not worry about it. And you must rename the two files of the two projects to the different name to distinguish them easily.

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT: That almost solves my problem, but... ASP.NET Core merges appsettings.json with appsettings.<environment>.json files at runtime. It is very likely, that Project B contains appsettings.production.json, but project A doesn't, so the file is copied and merged at runtime. It is quite difficult to write error prone script, that will delete appsettings.<environment>.json files only when not present in project A.

Comment: Did you want to write a error prompt that Project A does not include its own `appsettings.production.json` file due to some custom steps? Did you check if it's `Copy if newer` under Solution Explorer? Did you want to make a self-checking mechanism? If so, you could add these under Project A.csproj file:

Comment: <Target Name="Check" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="!Exists('$(TargetDir)xxx.appsettings.production.json')">
    <Error Text="xxx.appsettings.production.json is missing" />
  </Target>

Answer (score 0):

This issue raised it head again for me after a series of Visual Studio updates.

Although I couldn't prevent referenced project files being copied to the output folder, I could use the below code in the referencing projects config file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...

    <RunPostBuildEvent>Always</RunPostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="del /f &quot;$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

This deletes the cached output file after build which ensures it's always built. As such, it's files are always written last, overriding anything from referenced projects.